# Matching anything else but a date

Tags: regex

I'm using the REGEX below to effectively check if a string is a YYYY-MM-DD date.

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
```

How do I do the reverse and use a similar REGEX to check a string is NOT a date in this format.

Comment: Which language/tool are you using? Why do you need to reverse it? Just check it it doesn't match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative look-ahead to solve this:

```
 (?![0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})
```

Edit: After watching the post by Lucasus I've made a new regex to have a more strict validation.

- Year can be any combination of 4 digits, which e.g. allows dates pre 1900
- The month is in the range of 1-12
- Days in the range of 1-31,
- Validates in the format YYYY-MM-DD

New Regex:

```
(?!([0-9]{4})-([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])-([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches more than only a valid date (for example "3333-99-99"), You can use a longer expression:

```
^(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])-([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])-([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

If you want match everything but the date, use negative look-ahead, as Marcus wrote:

```
^(?!((19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])-([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])-([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])))$
```

The regex is from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449817/what-are-some-of-the-most-useful-regular-expressions-for-programmers)

Comment: Note that this matches the date in another format than given by the OP and does not support years outside the range of 1999-2999.

Comment: @Marcus, you're right, your format is reversed. Fixed. If you want years from other range (for example years from 0000 - 9999), you can simply change the beginning from "19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]" to "[0-9]{4}"

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-10-27','%Y-%m-%d')
except ValueError:
    print 'The string is NOT in the right format'
else:
    print 'The string is in the right format'
```

Indeed this isn't regex, but it might perform better - may be worth benchmarking...

Comment: Perform better in which language? And besides he's checking for NOT a date, it would be kind of backwards to Expect an Exception ;)

Comment: In Python. Actually in Python it does make sense to use the exception this way :)

Answer (score 0):

First, your regex doesn't ensure that the string **is** a date, just that it **contains** one.  If you wanted to make sure the string contains *nothing but* a date (according to your formulation), you would need to anchor it:

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$
```

...and the simplest way to ensure that the string that is *not* a date is to try to match it with that regex and negate the result.  How you do that depends on the language; in C# you could do this:

```
if ( !Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$") )
```

If you must do the check with the regex itself (for example, if you're using a simple regex-based validation control), you can use a negative lookahead, as other responders advised:

```
^(?![0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$).*
```

Starting from the beginning of the string (because of the `^`), the lookahead tries to match a date followed by the end of the string (`$`).  If that fails, the match position is reset to the beginning, and the `.*` goes ahead and consumes the whole string.