# Frequently used regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, editor

What are the regular expressions you use frequently for common tasks  like,

Clean up of strings(trim, case change etc)
Remove "New Line" characters
Replace XML TAGs (<>) with JSON braces { }
Adding "TABS" and "New Lines" to format XML/JSON
Validating/Finding emails / pincodes from text
etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Common Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331426/common-regular-expressions)

Comment: Its .Net centric, while what I am asking is not exactly same as there are some differences in support and syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions for reference on regular expressions.

http://geniuscarrier.com/common-regular-expressions-in-javascript/

[What are some of the most useful regular expressions for programmers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449817/what-are-some-of-the-most-useful-regular-expressions-for-programmers)